# Can Groovy coexist with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, coexistence

I've been reading about Groovy recently and noticed that Groovy was supported by Spring? I'm wondering if they can coexist in the same web application? Possibly use the best of both worlds if one does things better than the other? If so, anyone have good examples of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the the top notch web frameworks (Grails, kind of Groovy on Rails) is based on Groovy, Hibernate and ... Spring Framework. So the answer is Yes. Also note that for both Groovy and Spring Framework SpringSource is the lead development company.

Comment: Oh! Perfect. I failed at Google searching today. Thanks again!

Reference: http://grails.org/1.3.2+Release+Notes

Comment: A top notch framework for Swing GUI development, called Griffon, also exists. It's a fork of the excellent Grails web framework, with Swing retrofitted, so uses the same constituent technologies as Grails. SpringSource, a division of VMware (don't capitalize the "w"), offers training in these technologies at competitive rates. Another Groovy-based product, Gradle, supported by Gradleware (again, don't capitalize the "w"), is the build tool for these technologies. Together, they are known as Gr8, and you can attend their conferences for a reasonable fee, with early-bird discounts available.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is a language and Spring is a framework. They function separately, and as Spring is a Java framework, it can be used by Groovy.